# Is printing an empty string observable behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, state, language-lawyer, observable-behavior

In C++03 Standard observable behavior (1.9/6) includes *calls to library I/O functions*. Now I have this code:

```
printf( "" );
```

which is formally a call to a library I/O function but has no effect.

Is it observable behavior? Is the compiler allowed to eliminate it?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Just as much as code optimization does.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Yes, if the compiler is not allowed to do that I get extra machine code.

Comment: @Oli - even if it doesn't matter that doesn't make it not an interesting question.

Comment: Well, the 1.9/6 specifically says that yes, it's observable behavior and compiler can't eliminate it. I guess your real question is why, because we certainly wouldn't mind if it did that?

Comment: Are you sure it has no effect? Maybe it will trigger internally some timeout that flushes some buffers? Or buffers are flushed every N calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly observable if `sync_with_stdio` is `true`. When that's true, `printf("")` forces synchronization with `std::cout` output, flushing previously buffered output.

Comment: Are you sure `sync_with_stdio` may change how stdio performs, and not just how the C++ streams work, which might happen to cause strange things to the former?

Answer (score 2):

It would observable

- if the output is redirected and the file was closed, truncated, or somehow has become invalid for output
- if the stream state was 'bad' anyway

The point made about sync_with_... is also very relevant

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it, since the behavior might become more highly visible in multithreaded programming if the OS chooses to context switch when the thread invoking `printf` blocks for I/O.

In that case, it will definitely have an effect if the results depend on how the threads is interleaved.

Comment: That's true, but the question was whether or not printing "had no effect" and was therefore not "observable". I was merely providing one case where it would have a real effect. Nowhere did I claim that this was from the standard.

Comment: @Platinum: I do not thing that context switching counts. All code modifications may affect context switching, yet optimizations are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you C library can be written in a way that flushes the buffer based on time. In that case, printing of empty string can result in a flush, thus producing a visible effect.

Answer (score -3):

Of course this has observable behavior - it must generate a call to write() system call with the underlying file descriptor. Making a system call is very observable behavior.

Consider as an extreme example that the file descriptor in the kernel may be serviced by a device driver that sounds  siren every time it's write file operation is called (OK, somewhat of an artificial example, I'll admit :-) ...

Comment: couldn't the `write()` call quite legally *not* work on `0` terminated strings?

Comment: I would have thought that the library (which buffers) would do a no-nop as zero bytes will be added to the buffer. The only observable evidence is nmore CPU usage.

Comment: @Ed Heal - and if CPU usage is considered an observable behaviour then all optimisations are out!

Comment: What if my computer sounds a siren every time ram is modified?  Does incrementing an integer then qualify as observable behavior?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: LOL. I guess you wouldn't care - your life would be miserable anyway.

Comment: -1, wrong. There's no reason to assume a `write` call even exists. If the OS only has a `PUTCHAR(C)` call, the `printf` implementation will have to loop. And obviously looping over `""` will call `PUTCHAR` exactly zero times, i.e. non-observable.

Comment: @MSSalters you are right of course that there needed be a right call. The point I was trying to make is that if printf is implemented on top an abstraction outside the program (e.g. system call) that receives whole strings (e.g. write()) then that call will be made for a NULL string - hence it is observable.